# eval(parse(...))) pattern for potentially numeric values

Tags: r, eval

I came across the following code and wondering if there is a reason for this given that the `num` variable comes from a numeric column (integer or double).

```
num_val <- eval(parse(text = num %>% as.character()))
```

Could it be a pattern that is (was) useful for something in older versions of R?

Comment: That code is an anti-pattern and, honestly, pretty useless. Don’t copy it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that hasn't really changed for a very long time.

- It allows strings like "1+1" to be evaluated and stored as the result (i.e. 2).
- If `num` was already numeric, it would have the effect of rounding it to the value that `as.character()` would calculate.  Typically that value is not affected by the `options("digits")` setting and is usually much more precise, but it's not quite the same precision as used internally.
- If `num` held an integer, that would convert it to a double.
- If `num` held a vector of values, that would evaluate all of them, then only keep the last one.

I'd have to see the context, but I can't think of any useful reason to use code like that if `num` was known to be numeric.  Only the first reason (allowing users to enter expressions instead of numbers) would make sense.

Answer (score 3):

A very good general piece of advice is to **never** use the `eval(parse(` combination in your own code.  From the `fortunes` package:

```
> library(fortunes)
> fortune(106)

If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
   -- Thomas Lumley
      R-help (February 2005)
```

There is almost always a better alternative in R, the above code looks like a more complicated, hard to understand version of:

```
num_val <- as.numeric(as.character(num))
```

if the values in `num` are numbers, or a factor with numeric labels then this works (there is a slightly more efficient version in the FAQ).  The eval-parse method would work if `num` contained something like "c(1,4,6)" or "1:10", but in those cases it would probably be better to figure out where `num` is coming from that it would contain something like the above and figure out a better workflow.

Using `eval` and `parse` can be dangerous (if `num` contains some attack code, then this could cause major problems) and very hard to debug (google for "debug action at a distance").

That said, there is code out there where the programmers used `parse` and `eval` as a quick and dirty (but not best) way to do something, then that code was copied and modified and people took the quick and dirty approach to somehow be a reasonable approach, so things like this are out there.  But you best approach (for good code and learning to be a better R programmer) is to find better options and never use `eval(parse(`.

My own contribution to `fortunes` on this topic:

```
> fortune(181)

Personally I have never regretted trying not to underestimate my own future
stupidity.
   -- Greg Snow (explaining why eval(parse(...)) is often suboptimal, answering a
      question triggered by the infamous fortune(106))
      R-help (January 2007)
```

Comment: I actually slightly disagree with Thomas here: `parse` can (though rarely) be useful. So can `eval`. As you say, it’s the *combination* of the two that spells trouble.